# WebBrowser iframe shows NavigationCancelled

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

In my WebBrowser I have a page with an iframe to a Youtube video. The text 'NavigationCancelled' appears instead of the iframe. How do I fix it so that the youtube video appears?

Comment: Is it an secured page using https?

Comment: The page itself is https yes.

Comment: So you are viewing an http page in an iframe inside an https page. IE do not allow this due to some security consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are viewing an http page in an iframe inside an https page. IE do not allow this due to some security consideration. And WebBrowser control inherited these security restrictions.

On a desktop machine. You can toggle security setting of IE to solve his problem. (change "Display mixed content" to Enable)

However, your question is tagged `windows-phone-8`. Windows phone do not have such security setting so the solution above doesn't work.

Finally, if you have control of the web server, try to use http instead of https.

Comment: This is actually true of windows phone 8